# ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine in Django and Paho mqtt

Tags: python, django, apache, mqtt, windows-server-2012-r2

I am using paho MQTT to establish a connection with a mosquitto server on a windows 2012 r2 server. I have used 2 threads one for the main server process and another for establishing a connection with mosquitto server.
This is how I am establishing connection to MQTT.
mqtt.py file is placed in main project of Django along with manage.py

```
import random
client_id = f'python-mqtt-{random.randint(0, 1000)}'
def mqtt_connect():
    mqtt_connect.client = mqtt.Client(client_id)
    mqtt_connect.client.on_connect = on_connect  
    mqtt_connect.client.on_message = on_message 
    mqtt_connect.client.on_disconnect = on_disconnect 
    mqtt_connect.client.connect(config("CLIENT_PORT"),1883)
    mqtt_connect.client.loop_start()
```

and I have initialized the thread in **init**.py inside the main folder along with settings.py

```
import pymysql

pymysql.version_info = (1, 4, 0, "final", 0)
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()

import mqtt
import threading

x = threading.Thread(target=mqtt.mqtt_connect)
x.start()
```

The Django application is running on an apache server.

ISSUE:
Every time I receive a message from MQTT after certain intervals this error occurs,

```
ln1/lidIntact\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.817976 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532] <paho.mqtt.client.MQTTMessage object at 0x000000CC2B07DBC8>\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.817976 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532] ['ln1', 'lidIntact']\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.864827 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532] Exception in thread Thread-2:\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.864827 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532] Traceback (most recent call last):\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.864827 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532]   File "c:\\users\\administrator\\envs\\mqtt\\Lib\\site-packages\\pymysql\\connections.py", line 705, in _write_bytes\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.864827 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532]     self._sock.sendall(data)\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.864827 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532] ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.864827 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532] \r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.864827 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532] During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.864827 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532] \r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.864827 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532] Traceback (most recent call last):\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.864827 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532]   File "c:\\users\\administrator\\envs\\mqtt\\Lib\\site-packages\\django\\db\\backends\\utils.py", line 84, in _execute\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.864827 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532]     return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.864827 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532]   File "c:\\users\\administrator\\envs\\mqtt\\Lib\\site-packages\\django\\db\\backends\\mysql\\base.py", line 73, in execute\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.864827 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532]     return self.cursor.execute(query, args)\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.864827 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532]   File "c:\\users\\administrator\\envs\\mqtt\\Lib\\site-packages\\pymysql\\cursors.py", line 163, in execute\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.864827 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532]     result = self._query(query)\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.864827 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532]   File "c:\\users\\administrator\\envs\\mqtt\\Lib\\site-packages\\pymysql\\cursors.py", line 321, in _query\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.864827 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532]     conn.query(q)\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.864827 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532]   File "c:\\users\\administrator\\envs\\mqtt\\Lib\\site-packages\\pymysql\\connections.py", line 504, in query\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.864827 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532]     self._execute_command(COMMAND.COM_QUERY, sql)\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.864827 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532]   File "c:\\users\\administrator\\envs\\mqtt\\Lib\\site-packages\\pymysql\\connections.py", line 763, in _execute_command\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.864827 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532]     self._write_bytes(packet)\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.864827 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532]   File "c:\\users\\administrator\\envs\\mqtt\\Lib\\site-packages\\pymysql\\connections.py", line 710, in _write_bytes\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.864827 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532]     "MySQL server has gone away (%r)" % (e,))\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.864827 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532] pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2006, "MySQL server has gone away (ConnectionAbortedError(10053, 'An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine', None, 10053, None))")\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.864827 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532] \r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.880456 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532] The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.880456 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532] \r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.880456 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532] Traceback (most recent call last):\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.880456 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532]   File "c:\\python37\\lib\\threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.880456 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532]     self.run()\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.880456 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532]   File "c:\\python37\\lib\\threading.py", line 870, in run\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.880456 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532]     self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.880456 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532]   File "c:\\users\\administrator\\envs\\mqtt\\Lib\\site-packages\\paho\\mqtt\\client.py", line 3452, in _thread_main\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.880456 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532]     self.loop_forever(retry_first_connection=True)\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.880456 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532]   File "c:\\users\\administrator\\envs\\mqtt\\Lib\\site-packages\\paho\\mqtt\\client.py", line 1779, in loop_forever\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.880456 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532]     rc = self.loop(timeout, max_packets)\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.880456 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532]   File "c:\\users\\administrator\\envs\\mqtt\\Lib\\site-packages\\paho\\mqtt\\client.py", line 1181, in loop\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.880456 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532]     rc = self.loop_read(max_packets)\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.880456 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532]   File "c:\\users\\administrator\\envs\\mqtt\\Lib\\site-packages\\paho\\mqtt\\client.py", line 1572, in loop_read\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.880456 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532]     rc = self._packet_read()\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.880456 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532]   File "c:\\users\\administrator\\envs\\mqtt\\Lib\\site-packages\\paho\\mqtt\\client.py", line 2310, in _packet_read\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.880456 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532]     rc = self._packet_handle()\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.880456 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532]   File "c:\\users\\administrator\\envs\\mqtt\\Lib\\site-packages\\paho\\mqtt\\client.py", line 2936, in _packet_handle\r

[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.880456 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532]     return self._handle_publish()\r

[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.880456 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532]   File "c:\\users\\administrator\\envs\\mqtt\\Lib\\site-packages\\paho\\mqtt\\client.py", line 3216, in _handle_publish\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.880456 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532]     self._handle_on_message(message)\r

[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.880456 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532]   File "c:\\users\\administrator\\envs\\mqtt\\Lib\\site-packages\\paho\\mqtt\\client.py", line 3444, in _handle_on_message\r

[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.880456 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532]     self.on_message(self, self._userdata, message)\r

[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.880456 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532]   File "c:\\users\\administrator\\envs\\mqtt\\Lib\\site-packages\\django\\db\\models\\query.py", line 678, in first\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.880456 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532]     for obj in (self if self.ordered else self.order_by('pk'))[:1]:\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.880456 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532]   File "c:\\users\\administrator\\envs\\mqtt\\Lib\\site-packages\\django\\db\\models\\query.py", line 287, in __iter__\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.880456 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532]     self._fetch_all()\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.880456 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532]   File "c:\\users\\administrator\\envs\\mqtt\\Lib\\site-packages\\django\\db\\models\\query.py", line 1308, in _fetch_all\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.880456 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532]     self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.880456 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532]   File "c:\\users\\administrator\\envs\\mqtt\\Lib\\site-packages\\django\\db\\models\\query.py", line 53, in __iter__\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.880456 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532]     results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.880456 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532]   File "c:\\users\\administrator\\envs\\mqtt\\Lib\\site-packages\\django\\db\\models\\sql\\compiler.py", line 1156, in execute_sql\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.880456 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532]     cursor.execute(sql, params)\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.880456 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532]   File "c:\\users\\administrator\\envs\\mqtt\\Lib\\site-packages\\django\\db\\backends\\utils.py", line 66, in execute\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.880456 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532]     return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.880456 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532]   File "c:\\users\\administrator\\envs\\mqtt\\Lib\\site-packages\\django\\db\\backends\\utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.880456 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532]     return executor(sql, params, many, context)\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.880456 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532]   File "c:\\users\\administrator\\envs\\mqtt\\Lib\\site-packages\\django\\db\\backends\\utils.py", line 84, in _execute\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.880456 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532]     return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.880456 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532]   File "c:\\users\\administrator\\envs\\mqtt\\Lib\\site-packages\\django\\db\\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.880456 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532]     raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.880456 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532]   File "c:\\users\\administrator\\envs\\mqtt\\Lib\\site-packages\\django\\db\\backends\\utils.py", line 84, in _execute\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.880456 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532]     return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.880456 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532]   File "c:\\users\\administrator\\envs\\mqtt\\Lib\\site-packages\\django\\db\\backends\\mysql\\base.py", line 73, in execute\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.880456 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532]     return self.cursor.execute(query, args)\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.880456 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532]   File "c:\\users\\administrator\\envs\\mqtt\\Lib\\site-packages\\pymysql\\cursors.py", line 163, in execute\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.880456 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532]     result = self._query(query)\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.880456 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532]   File "c:\\users\\administrator\\envs\\mqtt\\Lib\\site-packages\\pymysql\\cursors.py", line 321, in _query\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.880456 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532]     conn.query(q)\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.880456 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532]   File "c:\\users\\administrator\\envs\\mqtt\\Lib\\site-packages\\pymysql\\connections.py", line 504, in query\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.880456 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532]     self._execute_command(COMMAND.COM_QUERY, sql)\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.880456 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532]   File "c:\\users\\administrator\\envs\\mqtt\\Lib\\site-packages\\pymysql\\connections.py", line 763, in _execute_command\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.880456 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532]     self._write_bytes(packet)\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.880456 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532]   File "c:\\users\\administrator\\envs\\mqtt\\Lib\\site-packages\\pymysql\\connections.py", line 710, in _write_bytes\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.880456 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532]     "MySQL server has gone away (%r)" % (e,))\r
[Tue Apr 27 10:54:54.880456 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 72980:tid 1532] django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2006, "MySQL server has gone away (ConnectionAbortedError(10053, 'An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine', None, 10053, None))")\r
```

I am new to this, so can anyone tell me if I'm handling threads wrong or like I read in other issues this is a python issue. I am using python 3.7 here.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by establishing a heartbeat signal with the hardware. The connection was getting aborted due to a long period of activity from hardware side.